# How to git add a whole folder

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and I am trying to git add my whole working directory but I receive the error message:

> **fatal**: pathspec 'folder' did not match any files.

I'm in the working dir when I do this command, what am I doing wrong?
Also, is it good practice to commit the whole folder instead of file by file?
Thank you

Comment: whats wrong with `git add .`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to add `folder` while you already are in `folder`.

```
$ cd my_folder
$ git init
$ git add my_folder # this is not going to work
```

Instead, add everything in the folder, rather than the folder itself:

```
$ cd my_folder
$ git init
$ git add .
```

---

To your other question, adding whole folders is fine, but only relevant when adding *sub*-folders. Again, you can't `git add` the folder that is your repository (`my_folder` above).

```
$ cd my_folder
$ ls
my_subfolder  other_things
$ git add my_subfolder # this is fine
```

The usual way to add everything in your working tree to your repo is `git add .`.

Comment: @sledge_909 Happy to help. Consider accepting the answer if it's the one that helped!

Answer (score 16):

You need to first check if you have added that folder in .gitignore file.

If not, then just do this.

```
git add --all
```

or

```
git add .
```

Answer (score 3):

If the folder contains space you need to enclose the name with quotation marks:

```
git add "New Folder/"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your folder is not under git version control, or you ignored it.
try to run `git add -A` to add your folder

Answer (score 2):

you must type the folder's name between quotation marks.

here is the pseudo-code:

```
git add 'folder name'
```

Comment: That's definitely not normally required. Maybe your folder includes a space in it? Or has special characters? In any case, quotes are unrelated to this being a folder.